# NSString to NSBezierPath strange glyphs for some standard fonts

Tags: objective-c, macos, fonts, bezier, nsbezierpath

I'm getting glyphs of individual characters from an NSAttributedString, then get the NSBezierPath with `appendBezierPathWithGlyphs:count:inFont:` and finally output the flattened path points to a NSArray (see my code below) to display them with OpenGL in Quartz Composer.

For some NSFonts, including standard ones (American Typewriter, Baskerville, ...), **the letters are totally wrong** (see the image below).

It might be important to say that I'm working with **French keyboard and language**.

```
NSBezierPath* path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];

NSTextStorage *storage = [[[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithString:character] autorelease];
NSLayoutManager *manager = [[[NSLayoutManager alloc] init] autorelease];
NSTextContainer *container = [[[NSTextContainer alloc] init] autorelease];

[storage addLayoutManager:manager];
[manager addTextContainer:container];


NSRange glyphRange = [manager glyphRangeForTextContainer:container];
NSGlyph glyphArray[glyphRange.length];
NSUInteger glyphCount = [manager getGlyphs:glyphArray range:glyphRange];

[manager getGlyphs:glyphArray range:glyphRange];

// ---- Necesary
[path moveToPoint: NSMakePoint(0, 0)];


// STRANGE CHARACTERS
[path appendBezierPathWithGlyphs:glyphArray count:glyphCount inFont:selectedFont];
```

[image: With Arial]
[image: With Baskerville]
Does someone knows the explanation of this behavior ? Is there a solution to **get the right path with these fonts** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't generate the glyphs for the font you use in `-appendBezierPathWithGlyphs:count:inFont:`. As you don't set `NSFontAttributeName` attribute to the `NSTextStorage` the glyphs are generated with default font.

Create your `NSTextStorage` with correct font and your problem will be solved :

```
NSTextStorage *storage = [[[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithString:character
                                                     attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : selectedFont}] autorelease];
```